# Notification sounds crackle and pop while playing audio 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, notification

I've had quite some issues with the sounds after upgrading from 16.04, but I got all to work properly with PulseEffects. The only downside is that now whenever I play any audio (be it mp3, youtube, spotify, some other media), and another sounds (like notification) plays over it, the speakers crackle and pop.

This is mighty annoying as my colleagues all contact me via Skype. I figure this has to do with some configuration of the audio channels, but I cant seem to find the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Would disabling the sound of the notifications solve the issue (as a workaround)?

Comment: That wouldn't really be a workaround as more an 'stop using it all together'. I do need the notification sounds. And it's not a huge issue by itself, but it seems to me it should be one easy to solve if you know where to look..

Comment: That makes sense. I use visual notifications and turn off the corresponding audio, since I find it annoying and with the visuals I don't miss anything anyway so the audio for me is unneeded. But I can see why you would like to fix the root of the issue. I hope you find a solution.